# Download of file through iframe in IE8 causing IE client area to not repaint

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a webapp that uses an iframe to stream a file download to the client. It seems to work fine for all browsers except for IE8. When IE8 is used, the 'File Download' dialog pops up, I pick a location and the file downloads. The issue here is that the 'File Download' dialog and the 'Save As' dialog still show. The page still seems to function except now a bunch of the page is hidden by the old dialogs still showing. Nothing seems to refresh the IE window except a repost of the page or moving to another area of the site through one of the visible menu items etc.

This seems to happen when the content-disposition is attachment. When it's set to inline I don't get this behaviour.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?